# How to write a "ghost" (or non-passable) text for a Kivy TextInput?

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

In a kivy app, I have some text-input widgets, I would like to label it as a ghost text. By ghost text, I mean it passes no value to the number to be called later on.

For example, say, I have two text input entries in a kivy app.

```
TextInput:
    text: '1st number'
    id: first_id
    input_filter: 'float'
    multiline: False

TextInput:
    text: '2nd number'
    id: second_id
    input_filter: 'float'
    multiline: False
```

When the app is run, the first text input has a default text "1st number" and the second text input has a default text "2nd number". I am linking them to a function that add the two floating numbers together via a method. The problem is if users didn't enter anything and press the "run" button, it will break the app. Is there a way to make the text non-passable to the function?

And also, I want it to be in the background, so that users don't have to tap the text input and then delete the '1st number' writing before entering a number, any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have created a small example the creates the behavior you wanted. I created a new widget with a **TextInput** and a **Label** and its only showing the label if the value is empty...

```
a = Builder.load_string("""

<FloatInput@FloatLayout>:
    empty_text: "Input a number"
    value: float(txt.text or '0.0')
    TextInput:
        id: txt
        input_filter: 'float'

    Label:
        center: txt.center
        size: self.parent.size or (300,300)
        text: "" if self.parent.value else self.parent.empty_text
        font_size: txt.font_size
        color: 0,0,0,1

BoxLayout:
    FloatInput:
        id: fi
    Label:
        text: "%s" % fi.value

""")




class SimpleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return a

SimpleApp().run()
```

You may use this class as your input widget...